# Find the volume of the region under $z=x^2+y^2$ over $R$ bounded by $x=y^2$ with double integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I couldn't figure out the limits of the double integral.This is my first question here so forgive me about any mistake and feel free to tell my mistakes to me.$$\int\int_Rx^2+y^2dA$$
In the answer key result is $$\int_{-1}^1\int_{y^2}^{2-y^2}(x^2+y^2)dxdy$$

Comment: could you possibly state the explicit form of your integral? otherwise its a little ambiguous what you mean

Comment: The region is unbounded.

Comment: I should delete this question right?

Comment: Check again the limits.

Comment: I guess they forget something in this question.I double check everything.

Comment: After the edit: $x = 2 - y^2$ is another bounding surface.

Answer (score 0):

The bounding surfaces are:
$$x= y^2,\qquad x = 2 - y^2,\qquad z = x^2 + y^2,\qquad z = 0.$$
The triple integral is:
$$\int_{-1}^1\int_{y^2}^{2 - y^2}\int_0^{x^2 + y^2}\,dzdxdy.$$
Why $[-1,1]$? Check the intersection points of $x = y^2$ and $x = 2 - y^2$.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate that.

Comment: @NehirAltun, then you can accept the answer.